# Problems with mysql-libs *after* installing MariaDB

Tags: centos, postfix, rpm, centos6, mariadb

I have installed MariaDB 5.3.3 on a Centos 6 server. In order to do that, I had to issue this command before installing the MariaDB-server rpm:

```
rpm -e --nodeps mysql-libs
```

And now mariadb and all the other software in the server is working fine.

Today I tried to upgrade the packages in my server the packages were successfully upgraded with the only exception of postfix which I can't install because of this error:

```
Running rpm_check_debug
ERROR with rpm_check_debug vs depsolve:
mysql-libs is needed by postfix-2:2.6.6-2.2.el6_1.x86_64
** Found 1 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
2:postfix-2.6.6-2.1.el6_0.x86_64 has missing requires of mysql-libs
Your transaction was saved, rerun it with: yum load-transaction /tmp/yum_save_tx-2012-02-13-09-487yg1lQ.yumtx
.. install failed!
```

Could anyone help me overcome this problem? I am pretty sure that the software in the `mysql-libs` package is already installed by mariadb packages but this information ins not in the rpm system.

Additional info:

- http://kb.askmonty.org/en/centos-5x6x-mysql-lib-conflicts-and-postfix
- https://answers.launchpad.net/maria/+question/163857

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not so much that the package is *conflicting*, it's more that you uninstalled a postfix *dependency* (postfix mysql integration) in getting MariaDB-server to install.

If you reverse your steps and reinstall mysql-libs again, you'll solve this problem (but probably lose MariaDB). You might just get lucky by installing the compat-libs however.

(Given the lack of answers, it might be worth it. I'll give it a shot when I get a spare moment on a Cent 6 VM)

Add the remi repository to your rpm repo by doing the following;

```
rpm -Uvh http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/beta/6/i386/epel-release-6-5.noarch.rpm
rpm -Uvh http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm
```

Then try to install the mysql-compat rpm...

```
rpm -Uvh http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/6/test/x86_64/compat-mysql55-5.5.11-1.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm
```

And if that works, see if you can update